# PowerShell: Import-csv and output values to log file (formatting)

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following to import users from a csv file and output them to the console:

```
$(Import-csv $SelectedFile | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddress)
```

This displays each EmailAddress on a separate line in the console but I want to output this to a log file too.

Using the following will do this but not a separate line for each EmailAddress like the above. Instead it just shows them on one line with no separator:

```
"$(Import-csv $SelectedFile | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddress)" | Tee-Object $UserMigrationLog -Append
```

Is it possible to do what I ask within this one command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You interpolate the result of `Import-CSV` into a single string. Just *remove* the subexpression `"$()"` and it will work:

```
Import-csv $SelectedFile | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddress | Tee-Object $UserMigrationLog -Append
```

Comment: Oh right. As simple as that! Excuse my ignorance but why does removing the subexpression change this?

Comment: Using a subexpression `$()` within a string `""` will cast the result of that subexpression to a single string